# Angular 6 and Karma/Jasmine issue - No Angular CLI

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

My app is currently on `Angular 6.1.9`, `Karma 2.0.0` and `Jasmine 2.4.1`. After Angular 6 upgrade, npm test fails. Chrome browser opens to indicate that Karma is connected. But I see `EXECUTED 0 OF 0 TEST CASES`. I'm forcing to run only 1 test -

```
describe("Check test", () => {
it("1 + 1 = 2", () => expect(1 + 1).toBe(2));
});
```

I also see this line - `Entrypoint undefined = index.html`. The app is not Angular CLI and converting to CLI project is not an option for now. Is there any config I'm missing?

Comment: Well it sounda like your missing the correct property "index" in angular.json or simply not providing entry point component in index.html. Can you update question with more project structure?

Comment: There is no `angular.json` in the project structure. I'm using webpack.config where I have this in the plugins, 

`new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      metadata: METADATA,
      chunksSortMode: helpers.packageSort(['polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'])
    }),`

Comment: Does your index.html include the root component? What cli are you running?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm not running any cli and converting to a CLI project is not an option for the app right now. All tests were running correctlt before upgrading to Angular 6.